# How would I get the results from this to end at a value of 2?

Tags: python

This is a countdown calculator that shows all even numbers from user input to 2. If the user inputs an odd number, it adds 1 to make the number even. I need it to stop at 2, but I'm not sure how.

```py
startVal = int(input("Enter a starting value:"))
loss = 2
if startVal % 2 == 1:
    startVal = startVal + 1
    for i in range(2, startVal + 1):
        startVal -= loss
        print(startVal)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, by doing `for i in range(2,startVal+1):`, how many times does the loop run? How many times does it need to run? Can you see a way to make the necessary adjustment? Bonus: read the documentation for `range` and make sure you understand how it works. Each time through the loop, *what value* will `i` have? Based on the documentation, can you think of a way to make it count *down* instead? Can you see a way to simplify the code, using this information?

Comment: The reason I am asking these questions is because I believe you already know everything that you need to know in order to solve the problem, and just need to think more clearly - i.e., that you don't actually have a question that requires publishing on Stack Overflow. Please keep in mind that this is *not a discussion forum*; we ideally want questions that *could potentially help someone else*. Someone else in a situation like yours would not realistically be able to find a post like this with a search engine.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Those are good questions, this is my 7th assignment in the last 2 hours so maybe you're right and I just need to review what I already know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all code inside a loop will execute will execute the number of times you specify in the loop condition

```
> for i in range (0,6):
      print("Hello")
```

would print the word 'Hello'  5 times. Please read on the concept of loops.
Meanwhile here is a working solution. (given the input is odd). Use this to figure out how you would do the same logic for an even number.

```
startVal=int(input("Enter a starting value:"))
loss=2
if startVal%2==1:
    startVal=startVal+1
    temp  = int((startVal/2) - 1)
    for i in range(0,temp):
     startVal-=loss
     print(startVal)
```

Enter a starting value:17

16

14

12

10

8

6

4

2

Comment: @Brainalingus. Python Loops, => https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp
 I have attached a W3S link. they have an editor where you can test what you have learnt

Answer (score 1):

Pythons range has a third arguement which defines step size

```
range(start: int, end: int, step: int) -> Iterable[int]
```

And with that you can make decrementing loops

With knowing that you will have the next

```
start_val = int(input("Enter a starting value:"))
# this can be made much simpler
# if start_val % 2 == 1:
#    start_val = start_val + 1
start_val += start_val % 2
for i in range(start_val, 1, -2):
    print(i)
```

Also, you can mention that `startVal` was renamed to `start_val`. Avoid using CamelCase in variable namings, as Python's PEP-8 defines naming conventions. Use snake_case for variables and functions and CamelCase for class names.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know to avoid CamelCase, my instructor wanted us to use it for all variables in her course. I thought it was strange since everything I see on here is snake_case

Comment: CamelCase is used in other languages (C and siblings, Java and so on), so it may be your instructors main language is not python

Answer (score 0):

range(start, end step)

for i in range(startVal,2,-2):
startVal-=loss
print(startVal)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).